# Between Two curve text Top/Left

Tags: android

Hell Sir,

1. I want to Below type Text With Curve  in android Code
       Hwo Can Create It. Given Link I want This Type Curve And text.

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fttF.png

Comment: see `Canvas#drawTextOnPath`

Comment: you can draw it by using canvas.drawArc().